# Persist entity in controller POST action for EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm trying to add some custom action in symfony [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/customizing-backend-actions.md), I just added a form view with no problem, but the problem is with this form POST action, it is another method of same controller, which works well, but when I do `persist()` and `flush()` for entity manager it just does nothing. This is my code, everything works as expected except that changes are not applyed in database.

```
/**
 * @Route("/product-segment/save/{id}", name="admin_product_segment_save")
 */
public function saveSegmentsAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:product')->find($id);

    foreach ($product->getSegments() as $segment)
    {
        error_log("Product has segment " . $segment->getId());
    }

    $product->removeAllSegments();

    foreach ($product->getSegments() as $segment)
    {
        error_log("Now prod has  " . $segment->getId());
    }

    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    foreach ($this->getRequest()->request->all() as $post_var => $segment_id)
    {
        if ($post_var == 'segment_id')
        {
            $segment = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Segment')->find($segment_id);
            $product->addSegment($segment);
        }
    }
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    // redirect to the 'list' view of the given entity
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin', array(
        'view'   => 'list',
        'entity' => 'Product',
    ));
}
```

**EDIT**: This is my entity relation

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Segment", mappedBy="products", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
protected $segments;
```

Comment: Do you have persist cascade and remove on your entity relationship?, also you want to flush as few times possible, so flush only once before the return.

Comment: @mr12086 I added code of entity relation, it's supposed to be persisted but I did some extra text and persisting is actually working, so the problem must be around cascading. BTW, the double call to persist and flush is just for logging and debug. thanx

Comment: That was it actually, the relation was not well specified in both sides

Answer (score 0):

First you should only call the flush once in your code, and if you have your object the way you do:

> $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>     $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:product')->find($id);

You don't have to persist it again. The entity manager already has that object.
Regarding the action not doing anything. Check if ManyToMany relation is defined Ok in both sides. And your method removeAllSegments does what you want it to do.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html